# How can I access an element in the hash map based on the element number?

Tags: mapping, hashmap, multimap

I have a hash map with 5 elements in it. I would like to display the mapped value and the key value of an element based on the (element id) user input. For instance, if the user enters 2, I would like to display the map value and the key for the element at #2 in the hash map.

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question without an answer; regardless of language or platform (which you've neglected to  mention,) a hashmap, by definition, is an unordered container. There *is* no element #2. The elements in a hashmap are not kept in any defined order.

Comment: hm... i was using c++ and i read somewhere that the elements in the container were ordered from lower to higher based on the key value.

Comment: The elements may be kept in an array based on *some function of* the key value, yes. It might be, for example, the key value mod 31 (assuming the key is an int), in which case the elements with key 5 and 37 would *both* be in the sixth slot. There's no meaningful definition of "the sixth element" for this reason.

Comment: Now, if the key is an `int`, and what you actually want is the element whose key is that particular `int`, then that's a whole different story -- that's precisely what maps do. You give it an int and an object, and then given that same int, you'll get that same object back.

Comment: yea. i knew that we can find the mapped value using the key value but i wanted to get both the key and the mapped value based on the element # in the map. i take it that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maps in general are unordered containers. However, if you're using Java then you can take advantage of the `LinkedHashMap` class that provides a consistent ordering over its elements.

This class still only gives you sequential access, not random access, so finding the nth element will be O(n). If you *really* want to have random access then you should consider using a `List` rather than a `Map`.

Comment: i am trying to do this in c++. is there any possibility with that?

Comment: @Praveen: Not that I know of.